# Managing user permissions for printing on a HP M577f MFP

Tags: permissions, printing, printer

I am trying to set up an HP M577f printer at a customers site. Since only a few users should be allowed to print in color, I set up accounts on the printer and added them to a group that is allowed to print in color.

What I can't figure out however is, how I can create a print job that is assigned to that user. When I specify the username in the print job properties, it can not be accessed on the printer when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this isn't the way user management works for this type of printers.

The permissions of whichever user is currently logged into the printer are applied. So there are two feasible options:

1. Logging into the printer, printing, and then logging out of the printer
2. Saving the document on a usb stick, log in, and print locally at the printer

Hope that helps people struggling with the non-existing documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of managing user permissions in a printer itself who is allowed to print x or y or with settings a or b. 
You can think different and use an application like [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info).
If you set the profiles on a central location and add permissions on the profiles allowing specific users to only use profiles with color allowed or not or specific printer you can do much more. Now the users print directly in black when they are not allowed to print in color and the machine doesn't need to do handle it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, there is no central location to define profiles. So it has to be done on the printer.

Comment: well in case you don't have a file server or can't set up a shared folder on a pc, you can just copy the profiles from one pc to another. will work the same.